# Geometries issues involving arc or circle

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We use the model-derivative api and the viewer from Forge in our platform, but we had issues with geometries containing arcs :

[Bad translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s44OG.png)

[Should be like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8odM.png)

Here's a link if you want to test by yourself

`Link to IFC sample` [bad_arc_geometries.ifc](https://pastebin.com/tbxKt11P)

Did i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

There an issue with the IFC extractor, the fix will be rolled out in the next version. sorry for the inconvinience.